# Showing that $\mu$ is a measure when continuous from above

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Statment

Let $\mu$ be a set function defined on a $\sigma$ -algebra. Show that $\mu$ is a measure
given that  $\mu \geq 0$, $\mu(\emptyset)=0$, $\mu$ is continuous from above and countably additive.

The attempt at a solution.

Let $E_n$ be a disjoint sequence in the $\sigma$ -algebra with  $E =  \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n $

Then $F_n = \bigcup_{m=1}^\infty E_m$ and $G_n = E\setminus F_n$ and $E = F_n \bigcup G_n$

$G_n$ is a decreasing sequence because $\mu$ is continuous above and so any sequence in the $\sigma$ -algebra is decreasing.

And since all $E_n$ is a disjoint sequence, $G_n = E\setminus F_n = $

So $\lim_{n\to \infty} \mu(G_n) = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty G_n$

Since $E_n$ is a disjoint sequence $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty G_n = \emptyset$

$E = F_n \bigcup G_n$

so $\mu(E) = \mu(F_n) + \mu(G_n)$ and so $\mu(E) = \mu(F_n)$

and $\mu(E) = \sum_{1}^{\infty} = \mu(E_n) = \lim\sum_{1}^{\infty}\mu(E_n) = \lim\sum_{1}^{\infty}\mu(F_n)$ so $\mu$ is a measure.

Comment: What is a "measurable"?

Comment: Sorry.  should be a measure

Comment: Wait, you want to prove a measure is a measure?

Comment: Sorry.  No.  a typo. $\mu$ is a set function and want to prove that it is a measure

Comment: Do you mean, in the given part that $\mu$ is finitely additive

Comment: yes.  isn't finitely additive and countably additive the same?

Comment: If it would be countably additive, it would already be a measure.

Answer (score 2):

Let $B_{n}=\cup_{i=1}^{n} E_{i}$. Notice, that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} B_{n} =E$ (The details are left to you!, but as a hint, $B_{n}$ is ncreasing!). $$\mu (E)=\mu(\lim B_{n})= \lim \mu(B_{n})=\lim \mu(\cup_{i=1}^{n} E_{i})= \lim \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \mu (E_{i}) =\sum\limits_{i=1
}^{\infty}\mu(E_{i}).$$ The seccond lime is because $B_{n}$ is increasing and $\mu$ is continuous... I will leave  the other equalities for you to check, not that hard!